# How to Convert the JNI jdoublearray to C's double* (pointer)

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I am not much aware about JNI environment and stuck here.
From Java layer to JNI, it is passing double[][] and double[] as an parameter,
How can convert these into C's double*.

Any one have any suggestion?

Comment: Please post your specific code, i.e. the Java file and the generated .h file.

Comment: Use the appropriate JNI API of course. Have you looked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it answer here:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_JavaArrayTest
(JNIEnv *env, jobject, jdoubleArray x, jdoubleArray y)
{ 
     long N        = env->GetArrayLength(x);           // Access the array length

     double* xPtr  = env->GetDoubleArrayElements(x,0); // Get C++ pointer to array data 
     double* yPtr  = env->GetDoubleArrayElements(y,0); // and "pin" array elements

     - - - - - -
}
```

Where O/1 defined as :

```
#define JNI_FALSE 0
#define JNI_TRUE 1
```

Comment: I really wish this was a complete example.  I get errors: 'request for member 'GetArrayLength' in something not a structure or union long N = env->GetArrayLength(plat);'